# CakePHP: Cannot read from a custom cache in 2.8.4?

Tags: cakephp, caching, cakephp-2.8

This is painfully simple, but I cannot determine why it simply will not work as the Cookbook suggests it will. I am getting a blank result when I run the following:

```
Cache::write('req_quals', $value, 'permacache');
Cache::read('req_quals', 'permacache');
```

The config looks like:

`Cache::config('permacache', array('engine' => 'File', 'path' => CACHE . 'permacache' . DS, 'duration' => '+9999 days'));`

- The write works. I know this because I'm looking directly into the tmp/cache/permacache folder and I see the file with its contents inside.
- I can write/read this value without any problem if I remove the 'permacache' from both lines.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Cake calculates `duration`, +9999 days returns a negative duration. You should avoid being a *cool guy* and just use `+999 days` as the documentation [subtly suggests](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html).